# Try to Spill Down a Dynamic Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Using Excel 365.

I have some text data in columns **A** and **B** like:

```
101r    MC
101r    TU
101r    VV
101r    VL
w257    HU
w257    QI
w257    JJ
w257    YW
315L    GD
315L    OO
315L    NL
w257    BHU
```

that I want to summarize in 2-D format

in **D1** I enter the formula:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,LEN(A:A)))
```

which works and spills down nicely.  In **E1** I enter:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B:B,A:A=D1))
```

which also works and spills across nicely.  I then **manually** copy **E1** downward to get:

[image]

I would like the propagation of the **E1** formula to be dynamic.

**What I have tried:**

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B:B,A:A=INDEX(D:D,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(D:D)))))
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B:B,A:A=INDIRECT("D" & SEQUENCE(COUNTA(D:D)))))
```

Neither of these formulas spills down *(or even works at all)*.  However, by itself, the following part does work:

```
=INDEX(D:D,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(D:D)))
```

Is it possible to drag **E1** downwards dynamically ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=INDEX(D:D,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(D:D)))` just duplicates the results in `D1:D3`, which doesn't get you anywhere different than referencing `D1#` directly.

I do not think it is possible. But perhaps these attempts will get you or someone else closer?

I tried a mixed formula (relies on both array calculation and implicit intersection) utilizing the [implicit intersection operator (@)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34). I also replaced `D:D` with `D1#` to dynamically reference just the spilled range, using the [spilled range operator (#)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Spilled-range-operator-3dd5899f-bca2-4b9d-a172-3eae9ac22efd).

This gives the formula `=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B:B,A:A=@$D$1#))` which can be manually copied-pasted to all the cells in **E1** through **E3** without the **D1** relative reference your formula needed.

[image]

One would think that instead of copy-pasting this formula, it could be entered to all the cells as [CSE array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-array-formula-E43E12E0-AFC6-4A12-BC7F-48361075954D), by selecting **E1** through **E3**, entering the formula, and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. However, it appears Excel does not support spilling out from a CSE array formula. Following the calculation steps in E3 through the *Evaluate Formula* dialog, it gets to `TRANSPOSE({"GD";"OO";"NL"})`, but then somehow the final step turns this into `MC`. Maybe this is an Excel bug? In any case, it helps illustrate the difficulty a spreadsheet program might have in interpreting inputs in different dimensions.

[image]

I also tried the most obvious thing, `=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B:B,A:A=D1#))`. This just returns an `#N/A` error because `FILTER(array, include, [if_empty])` is not defined to accept 2-dimensional `include` arguments. What does it mean to filter an [Nx30] array with an `include` argument of dimension [Nx2]? Spilling to suit your question seems reasonable, but Microsoft must not have thought of this or thought it was generally useful and unambiguous enough to implement.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts............I appreciate your help............